# Change two value with onclick

Tags: javascript, php

unfortunately, the Javascript does not work as desired. I would like to reach onclick that in the textarea the value is changed. At the same time, the value should also be changed in the input.

```
 <textarea class="input"  style="width:100%;font-size:12pt;font-family: ArialMT, Verdana;font-weight: bold;height:100px;color:black" name="adresse" readonly="readonly" id="street"></textarea>
            <input style="width:130px;text-align: left" class="input" type="text" name="kundennr" id="kundennr" value="10000">

 <a href="#openModal">Kunden</a>
        <div id='openModal' class='modalDialog'>
    <div>
        <a href='#close' title='Close' class='close'>X</a>   

    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `kunde` ORDER BY `kundennummer` ASC";    
     foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $nav) {    
    $address = $nav['adresse']; 
    $name = $nav['kundennummer'];    
     echo " <a>$address</a> 
    <a> |  Kundennr: </a><a href='#' onclick='changeit(this);'>$name</a><br>";              
            }
        ?> 
    </div>
        </div>
        <script>function changeit(el) { 
            var inhalt = el.text;
            var db_address = '<?php echo $address; ?>';
            document.getElementById('kundennr').value=inhalt;
            document.getElementById('street').value =db_address;
        }
        </script>
```

UPDATED sorry i forget the modalbox.

Comment: First off the value of the Input named "street" will be set to '<?php echo $address; ?>' literally, because php is evaluaded on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function changeit(el) is generated only once with the last $address;

Teoretically you can include the function definition in the foreach statement and generate n-version of this function but this would be a horrible approach.

You should send array of addresses to javascript and work with it

```
<code>
var js_addresses = json_encode($addresses);
</code>
```

Comment: document.getElementById('street').value =<?php echo json_encode($uadresse); ?>; Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

First I have removed your PHP but retained the variable names $address and $name.
If I read your code correctly you want to put the value in $address into the textarea and the content of the input to the value of $name.

You need to modifiy your code just slightly. Read the value of $address via the link you are providing, by giving it an id in the example below "address" and access it's innerHTML. You have no direct access to the PHP variables on the front end only if you set them somewhere.
1. Add an id attribute to the address link.
2. replace your JS code with the JS code below
3. everything should work fine.

```js
function changeit(el) { 
        var inhalt = el.text;
        var db_address = document.getElementById("address").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('kundennr').value=inhalt;
        document.getElementById('street').value =db_address;
    }
```

```html
<textarea class="input"  style="width:100%;font-size:12pt;font-family: ArialMT, Verdana;font-weight: bold;height:100px;color:black" name="adresse" readonly="readonly" id="street"></textarea>
        <input style="width:130px;text-align: left" class="input" type="text" name="kundennr" id="kundennr" value="10000">


<a id="address">$address</a> 
<a> |  Kundennr: </a><a href='#' onclick='changeit(this);'>$name</a><br>
```